# how do I create a DOMSelection object from a specific node?

Tags: javascript, webkit, dom-selection

My javascript is not that good so I can only hope this makes sense.  I want to create a DOMSelection object like the one that gets returned from

```
window.getSelection()
```

from an onclick of the node. so lets say i have this jQuery listener setup like this:

```
$("#target").click(function() {
    var sel = createSelectionFromNode(this);
});
```

I only want the range to be from the beginning of the node to the end of the node.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I am specifically looking for WebKit compatible solutions, it's ok to ignore IE.  Thanks for any help.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8j4Bf/

in the example, clicking on the text should return a DOMSelection object like:

```
DOMSelection
anchorNode: Text
    attributes: null
    baseURI: "http://jsfiddle.net/8j4Bf/"
    childNodes: NodeList[0]
    data: "HTML"
    firstChild: null
    lastChild: null
    length: 4
    localName: null
    namespaceURI: null
    nextSibling: null
    nodeName: "#text"
    nodeType: 3
    nodeValue: "HTML"
    ownerDocument: HTMLDocument
    parentElement: HTMLSpanElement
    parentNode: HTMLSpanElement
    prefix: null
    previousSibling: null
    textContent: "HTML"
    wholeText: "HTML"
    __proto__: Text
anchorOffset: 0
baseNode: Text
baseOffset: 0
extentNode: Text
extentOffset: 0
focusNode: Text
    attributes: null
    baseURI: "http://jsfiddle.net/8j4Bf/"
    childNodes: NodeList[0]
    data: "HTML"
    firstChild: null
    lastChild: null
    length: 4
    localName: null
    namespaceURI: null
    nextSibling: null
    nodeName: "#text"
    nodeType: 3
    nodeValue: "HTML"
    ownerDocument: HTMLDocument
    parentElement: HTMLSpanElement
    parentNode: HTMLSpanElement
    prefix: null
    previousSibling: null
    textContent: "HTML"
    wholeText: "HTML"
    __proto__: Text
focusOffset: 0
isCollapsed: true
rangeCount: 1
type: "Caret"
```

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like document.getSelection() ? I'm a bit confused, so I apologize in advance.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/8j4Bf/1/

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.getSelection